# Angularjs:- button change based on json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I am working on a project based on angularjs and fetching data from json..There is a problem I am stuck up with and was not getting a solution to..

The below is the Html code:-

```
<div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="profile in updatedProfile" ng-if= "profile.show">  
    <!-- Panel in owl carousel -->
    <div id="discover " ng-class="discover_image">
        <li style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
            <div class="thumbnail_photo">
                <button class="close" ng-click="remove(profile)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                <a href="#/discover/{{profile.basic.username}} " target="_blank"><span class="discover_pic_container" style="background:url({{profile.photo_details.photos[0].domain_name+profile.photo_details.photos[0].medium}}) no-repeat center top"></span></a>
                <div class="discover_transparent">
                    <div class="discover_name">{{profile.basic.display_name }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="recent_join_user_info">23 yrs, 5'4", Gujarati, Hindu Mumbai, India</div>
            <button class="discover_connect_btn btn btn-lg " ng-click="connect(profile)" ng-if="member">Connect</button>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

The below is my controller code snippet:-

```
AppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl', ['$scope', 'ProfileData', '$timeout', function($scope, ProfileData, $timeout) {

    //Profile data above is a factory created to connect with the discovery.json
    var promise = ProfileData.query();
    promise.$promise.then(function(response) {

        $scope.profile = response.data;
   //     console.log($scope.profile);
        var profile = $scope.profile;
        for (i = 0; i < profile.length; i++) {

           // console.log(data[0].account.membership)
            profile[i]["show"] = true;
           // console.log(profile[i]);
            //console.log(profile[i].account.membership)

            if(profile[i].account.membership == "free")
                {
                    console.log("This account is free");
                    $scope.member=true;
                }
            else if(profile[i].account.membership == "premium")
                {
                    console.log("This acocunti snot");
                    $scope.member=false;
                }
            else
            {
             console.log("unknown member")   
            }

        }

        $scope.alert_message = "Sorry! You don't have any Shortlisted Profile to check";
        $scope.seeAllUrl = "member_who_shortlisted_you";
        // Get the size of an object
        var totalNumberOfProfile = profile.length;


        //console.log(totalNumberOfProfile);
        $scope.totalNumberOfProfile = totalNumberOfProfile;
        $scope.categoryOfProfile = "Member Who Shortlisted You";
```

Now I want to change the button depending upon the account membership I am getting from the json file..

By `default it is Connect but have three more button for different conditions`..

I have tried to use ng-if and getting stuck up and have no clue how to change the button based on the data..

I am a newbie on angular..please help me out..Thanks

Comment: using which parameter you have to change the button?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle/ plunker?

Comment: @RajaSekar I have used ng-if="member" and in the controller have put $scope.member=true so I can display button for member whose account is free

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix, Use 'if' conditions like the following

```
<div ng-if="member=='true'">
 <button>Button_1</button>
</div>

<div ng-if="member=='false'">
 <button>Button_2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes `ng-if="member=='false'"` is just like `ng-if="key=='value_expected'"` condition check

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one condition for your button user "ng-switch":

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
 < <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier, you can use `ng-switch`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/uvpx4eq5/).

```
<form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
 <select ng-model="condition">
 <option value="1">Condition one</option>
 <option value="2">Condition two</option>
 <option value="3">Condition three</option>
 </select>
 <div ng-switch="condition">
   <button ng-switch-when="1">
    Condition one!
   </button>
   <button ng-switch-when="2">
    Condition two!
   </button>
   <button ng-switch-when="3">
    Condition three!
   </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATED**

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/71jrq01o/).

```
<form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
  <div ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
    Yor profile is {{profile.account.membership}}
    <div ng-switch="profile.account.membership">
      <button ng-switch-when="free">
        free profile!
      </button>
      <button ng-switch-when="premium">
        premium profile!
      </button>
      <button ng-switch-when="unknow">
        unknow profile!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And JS

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
$scope.condition = '1';
$scope.profiles = [{
  account: {
    membership: "free"
  }
}, 
{
  account: {
    membership: "premium"
  }
}, 
{
  account: {
    membership: "unknow"
  }
}];});
```

Comment: I was trying to work with switch but am not sure as to what conditions I have to use profile[i].account.membership in the html..so am not sure how to use switch in this scenario